# Consider each line generated by a command as a line in a script

Tags: bash, line

I have this simple script :

```
#!/bin/bash

dates_and_PID=$(ps -eo lstart,pid)

echo ${dates_and_PID::24}
```

And I would like each line to be cut at the 24th character. Nevertheless, it considers the variable `dates_and_PID` as a single line, so I only have one line that is generated. Whereas I would like it to be cut for each line.

I am practicing but the final goal would be to have the script change the dates from `Mon Nov 11 2020` to `11/11/20`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like that? `ps -eo lstart,pid | cut -b 1-24`

Comment: Do you want `dd/mm/yy` or `mm/dd/yy`? November 11 is a somewhat inappropriate example.

Comment: If you want only the first column, why not `ps -eo lstart`?

Comment: In part, you're running into [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something else!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566) -- expansions need to be quoted for newlines to be treated as part of the literal data rather than as word separators.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the input line by line, instead of reading everything into a single variable. Something like this should do the trick:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
  echo "${line::24}"
done < <(ps -eo lstart,pid)
```

Comment: Consider making it `while IFS= read -r line; do` -- `IFS=` stops leading and trailing whitespace from being silently removed; `-r` prevents backslashes from being consumed. Using both together means your `$line` actually contains the line precisely as it was in input.

Comment: Both very valid additions. I didn’t want to over-complicate the answer, given the questioner’s obvious unfamiliarity with the language.

Answer (score 0):

You can pipe stdout to `while` loop:

```sh
ps -eo lstart,pid | while read line; do
  echo "${line::24}"
done
```

Comment: The answer by Andrew Vickers avoids the bug described in [BashFAQ #24](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024), which this answer is subject to. Doesn't matter if all you're trying to do is `echo`, does matter if one starts trying to set variables inside the loop.